# Replacing diagonal elements of square matrix without looping

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have a square matrix n x n & I also have a vector which is n x 1. I want to replace the diagonal elements with the values in my vector.

Is there a way of doing this in Matlab without looping?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
matrix(1:n+1:end) = vector;
```

Explanation: if you use a single index into a matrix (that's called [linear indexing](http://matlabrecipes.com/matlab-linear-indices/)), Matlab counts the elements down the first column, then second column etc. A step of `n+1` thus defines the diagonal.